# my $fltyp = system("file -b $LoadDir/$file"); not fetching any value

Tags: perl

Using below command to fetch file encode type but not getting and value.

my $fltyp = system("file -b $LoadDir/$file");

while printing $fltyp nothing is coming.

Regards,
Sudhanshu

Comment: File location we are string into $LoadDir and $file is the file name.

Comment: `system` returns the exit status of a program, not its output. You want to use backticks (aka `qx()` operator and `readpipe` function).

Comment: my $fltyp = system("file -b infdev/shared/2013042316.txt");

Comment: That will just run the command, which *prints out* the file type to standard output.  That's a very roundabout way of doing `print("ASCII English text\n");` or whatever.  If you want to *capture* the result of the command inside a Perl variable, you need to use \`...\` or one of the pipe functions.

Comment: yes we wanted to save the command output into the perl variable

Answer (score 3):

You're getting exit value from your command and not output. Did you try,

```
my $fltyp = `file -b $LoadDir/$file`;
```

Comment: this command is not working actually we are running code into perl  file under linux env

Answer (score 3):

The [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) call doesn't return the output of a command, but a status number showing success or failure.

You want to read about "backticks" or "[pipe open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)". Be aware that [backticks rely on your shell](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-call-backticks-without-shell-processing?) to parse the command.